# Any Equivalent of strstr in Windows Kernel Mode?

Tags: c, visual-c++, driver, kernel, wdk

I am writing a windows kernel mode driver in which I will have to manipulate lots of strings. Everywhere it has been advised to use "Safe String" functions instead of normal C functions. However, many of the string functions haven't been implemented e.g. strchr, strstr.

My question is whether there are any functions which I can use to search for strings within strings in kernel mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regular C runtime functions like strstr() in a driver.  Avoid focusing on finding a safe version of that function, none exists.  There's no scenario where strchr() or strstr() can corrupt memory unintentionally.  They only read, they don't write.  They can certainly cause a blue screen if the input strings are not properly zero-terminated, producing an access violation.  But that was a bug elsewhere.

Comment: Can't it cause some kind of certification denial (WHQL) from MS? It's one of the rules - to use only kernel APIs

Comment: Actually [Safe Versions Do Exist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563642(v=vs.85).aspx) but I would recommend using the `UNICODE_STRING` versions anyway if possible.